# My shape will not show up

Tags: ios, xcode, uitouch

Hello I am trying to draw a circle around a point in `UITouch` for iOS.  I would also like to draw crosshairs that intersect at the point as well but I have not gotten that far yet.  This should be able to happen at up to 10 touch points which is why you will see the for loop in the beginning. Any help would be much appreciated.

I list point in my globals because I use it across `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded`. I need the shapes to display until new touch points are initiated.  I am fairly new to all of this and it is a bit overwhelming.

Thanks for you time.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    radius = 10;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {


        point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        NSLog(@"X: %.3f Y: %.3f Began", point.x, point.y);
    }

    self.timestampstart = [NSDate date];

}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.timestampend = [NSDate date];
    self.duration.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.3f s", [self.timestampend timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timestampstart]];

    NSLog(@"X: %.3f Y: %.3f Ended. Duration %.3f", point.x, point.y, [self.timestampend timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timestampstart]);

}
```

Comment: Your question is too generic. You need to describe what you want, what does not work and at which point in the code it is. Nobody has the time to debug your whole source code to find the error, sorry.

Comment: The code currently logs the correct coordinates for the touch.  But it won't draw the circle.  I am unsure if I am using CGContext wrong or if there is something else not there that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you cannot use Core Graphics within this method. Usually, the `drawRect` method of a `UIView` is the place where you want to use this.

Maybe it is better to just add a custom `UIView` subclass (that represents your circle) using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`? So you have every concern where it belongs: *What* should happen when somebody taps the view and *how* the object you draw then should look like. Two concerns, nicely separated. (*Separation of concerns* is or at least will be your friend, trust me.)

Comment: I will look into trying to switch everything to the drawRect methodology.  I looked into UITapGestureRecognizer but it seems like something the is used more for the tap gesture and not the full spectrum of user situations (swipes, movements, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have your `UITouch` methods inside your `UIView`. You do not need a separate UIView for drawing, but you must move the drawing stuff into the method `drawRect`. Put one call of the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect` method in your `touchMoved` method (which I am missing in your code!), and iOS will do the rest.

Once you inform iOS that you need a screen redraw by calling `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect`, it will by itself call `drawRect` for the next screen redrawing cycle. Do yourself a favor and read the about the background [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay).

The way you do it now just means that the drawing will never happen on the screen.